# MonoTouch Dialog. Buttons with the Elements API

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Is it possible to create buttons on the view using only Elements API?

```
var root = 
    new RootElement ("LoginScreen"){
        new Section ("Enter your credentials") {
            new EntryElement ("Username", "Your user name", "user1"),
            new EntryElement ("Password", "Your password", "", isPassword:true),
    },
    new Section () {
        new RootElement ("Login"){ 
               //Here should be a button
        }
   },
   new Section () {
        new BooleanElement ("Save your credentials", false),
   },
};

var dv = new MainController (root, true){ Autorotate = true };
navigation.PushViewController (dv, true);
```

I know it's possible with Reflection API using `OnTapAttribute`, but I wonder how to do that with Elements API.

And when user taps on the button it should Push another view controller...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh I guess I can use `StyledStringElement` like that

```
new StyledStringElement ("Login", delegate{ DoLogin (); })
```