# MonoTouch Dialog's UITableView. How to handle taps?

Tags: c#, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

MonotouchDialog makes it very easy to create UITableView Dialogs, but sometimes questions like that one popup:

[MonoTouch Dialog. Buttons with the Elements API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666356/monotouch-dialog-buttons-with-the-elements-api)

Now, I have a similar problem but quite different:

```
List<User> users = GetUsers();

var root = 
   new RootElement ("LoginScreen"){
     new Section ("Enter your credentials") {
       foreach(var user in users)
         new StyledStringElement (user.Name, ()=> {
            // tap on an element (but which one exactly?)
         }
     ),
   }

navigation.PushViewController (new MainController (root), true);
```

Now, the second parameter of `StyledStringElement`'s constructor has the type of `NSAction` delegate, and doesn't take any arguments, now I dunno how to determine exactly which element been tapped.

How to get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was `Tapped` then it has been selected. So you should be able to inherit from `StyleStringElement` and **override** its `Selected` method to accomplish the same goal.

e.g.

```
class UserElement : StyleStingElement {
    public UserElement (User user) { ... }

    public override Selected (...)
    {
        // do your processing on 'user'
        base.Selected (dvc, tableView, indexPath);
    }
}
```

For [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit) I created a new ***Element** for every item I had, [TestSuiteElement](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit/blob/master/NUnitLite/TouchRunner/TestSuiteElement.cs), TestCaseElement, TestResultElement... to be able to customize each of them and adapt (a bit) their behaviour but I did not use this `Selected` to replace `Tapped`. You might want to check but it would not fit with your code pattern to create elements.

Answer (score 2):

### "...a Flower by any other name?"

If you look closely NSAction's are just delegates. I prefer to pass Action / Func into those params the reference for which is contained within the...container controller.

So lets so you have a UINavigationController that pushes a DialogViewController. When your element is selected you provide the unique user that you've passed to the Element and go from there :-)

```
public class MyNavController : UINavigationController
{
    Action<User> UserClickedAction;

    public MyNavController()
    {
        UserClickedAction = HandleUserClicked;
    }

    public void HandleUserClicked(User user)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't get it.. how's that applicable to my situation?